# R - How to end function and return NA?

Tags: r, function

Sorry this seems like a very easy question but I can't figure it out.
I have this small piece of code in the middle of my function:

```
if(num > length(unique_state)) stop(NA,call. = F)
```

What I want is if the result of the IF STATEMENT is TRUE, then just stop the function and rerun NA to the user. However, with the above code I also get a message:

```
Error: NA
```

How do I end a function and return NA?

Comment: `if(num > length(unique_state)) return(NA)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

have you tried `return()`?

```
f=function(x) {

  for(i in 1:100){
    x=x+i
    ##interesting part here
    if(x>44) return(NA)
  }
  x     }
```

Comment: note to self: if function 'f' is part of another vector function that *requires* product vector to have same dimension as input vector, then return(NA) will cause unintended consequences. in such a situations, return("") works better.